# WPF datagrid combobox column: how to manage event of selection changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a datagrid, with a combobox column

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="DataGridComboBoxColumnBracketType" Width="70" Header="Tipo di staffa" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">                    
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

I want an event that is fired only when the user changes the value into the combobox. 
How can I resolve this?

Comment: You need to change it back to how you previously had it with the Selector.Selected and using the grid. In order to access the ComboBoxItem I believe you would have to drill down into the ComboBox itself.

Comment: What's the problem? Is it just that the handler doesn't get invoked?  I wonder about the scope -- maybe the style has to be defined in a root resource dictionary.

Comment: Why can't you just subscribe to `PropertyChanged` on `type` in viewmodel??

Comment: @Maverik do you mean that I need to manage this issue into the set of type property?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution to this on [CodePlex](https://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/49358). Here it is, with some modifications:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="Whatever">                    
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
               <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="SomeSelectionChanged" />
          </Style>
     </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>           
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

and in the code-behind:

```
private void SomeSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
     var selectedItem = this.GridName.CurrentItem;

}
```

Comment: This does not work for routed events like DropDownClosed

Answer (score 6):

And the xaml code provided by @kevinpo from CodePlex and help from [David Mohundro's blog](http://mohundro.com/blog/2008/11/19/programmatically-adding-eventsetters-in-wpf/), programatically:

```
var style = new Style(typeof(ComboBox));
style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(SomeSelectionChanged)));
dataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle = style;
```

Answer (score 4):

To Complete Kevinpo answer, for the code behind you should add some protection  because the selectionChanged event is triggered 2 time with a datagridcolumncombobox:

1) first trigger  : when you selected a new item

2) Second trigger : when you click on an other datagridcolumn after you selected a new item

The problem is that on the second trigger the ComboBox
value is null because you don't have changed the selected item.

```
private void SomeSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    if (comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        YOUR CODE HERE
    }
}
```

That was my problem, I wish it will help someone else !

Answer (score 1):

The problem of getting SelectionChanged events to fire on DataGridComboBoxColumn cells was one that plagued me recently. I used the following solution:

```
 private void DataGridView_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.DisplayIndex == 3) //Use this IF statement to specifiy which combobox columns you want to attach the event to.
        {
            ComboBox? cb = e.EditingElement as ComboBox;
            if (cb != null)
            {
                // As this event fires everytime the user starts editing the cell you need to dettach any previously attached instances of "My_SelectionChanged", otherwise you'll have it firing multiple times.
                cb.SelectionChanged -= My_SelectionChanged;
                // now re-attach the event handler.
                cb.SelectionChanged += My_SelectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then set up your custom SelectionChanged event handler to whatever you need:

```
private void My_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your event code here...
    }
```