# WPF ComboBox SelectionChanged event firing twice

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls

In my `DataGrid` I am using `DataGridComboBoxColumn` as follows. Its `SelectionChanged` event (defined below) always fires twice - once when I click on an item, and then again when I select the new item from the dropdown. When I click on the item that I want to change the SelectionChanged event fires and shows the old value, and then when I select on a new value it fires again and correctly show the new value. But I want the event to be fired only when I select a new value for the combobox.

**Question**: What is causing this behavior and how can the issue be fixed?

**Remark**: Many users online seem to have similar issues posted [here](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=MWTMX9so_qTk2g_jobSIAQ&q=wpf%20combobox%20selectionchanged%20fires%20twice&oq=wpf%20combobox%20selectionchanged%20&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgDMgUIABDJAzICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADoICAAQ6gIQjwE6CAgAELEDEIMBOgsILhCxAxDHARCjAjoCCC46DgguELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgUIABCxAzoICC4QxwEQowI6CAguEMcBEK8BOgsIABCxAxCDARDJA1DQDljnSWCQb2gBcAB4AIABpwKIAZ0FkgEFOC4wLjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEK&sclient=psy-ab) but none of them helped resolve my issue - maybe, the context is a bit different here. Moreover, the XAML and the code seem ok as it correctly displays the combobox values along with the correctly combox selected values for each row in the grid. Plus, the SelectionChanged event does correctly show the newly selected value but when it fires the second time. Similar code is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21237751/1232087).

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="StartTime" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding localTime}" ItemsSource="{StaticResource localTimeList}">
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
           <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="MyComboBoxColumn_SelectionChanged"/>
        </Style>
     </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

**The event**:

```
private void MyComboBoxColumn_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    var selectedVal = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Debug your events using https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf, you'll get a better idea of what's currently happening.

Comment: If other users may have better suggestion, I'll implement that. For now, I resolved the issue by using `if (!comboBox.IsDropDownOpen){ return;}` before getting `comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();` value. This worked because, by default, DropDown of the combobox is hidden (not open), and first time when I click on an item the SelectionChanged (for some reason) gets called. But at that time the IsDropDownOpen is still false. Afterwards, the dropdown opens and shows the list of item to select an item from. Hence, at the second time I can execute the desired code of the `SelectionChanged ` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is causing this behavior?

The `SelectionChanged` event is raised initially when you enter the edit mode and the `SelectedItem` property is being bound to your source property.

> How can the issue be fixed?

The easiest way to handle this is to check whether the `ComboBox` has been loaded and simply return from the event handler immediately if it hasn't:

```
private void MyComboBoxColumn_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    if (!comboBox.IsLoaded)
        return;

    //handle an actual selection here...
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion of using `IsLoaded` is doing the same job as using `IsDropDownOpen` (as suggested in my comment). But I like your suggestion since most users are more familiar of `IsLoaded` property than `IsDropDownOpen`. Moreover, I like your response since it has better explanation of what's causing the error. Thank you.

Comment: This solution also worked for similar problem with ListView.  Thank you.