# What is the equivalent of a WPF EventSetter in WinUI3?

Tags: windows-community-toolkit, winui, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I want to catch the DataGridComboBoxcolumn SelectionChanged event in WinUI3 (Community Toolkit DataGrid).

In WPF,  there is a solution like below by using EventSetter.
But I cannot find an alternative in WinUI3.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="Whatever">                    
     <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
               <EventSetter Event="SelectionChanged" Handler="SomeSelectionChanged" />
          </Style>
     </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>           
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

[WPF EventSetter]
[WPF datagrid combobox column: how to manage event of selection changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322271/wpf-datagrid-combobox-column-how-to-manage-event-of-selection-changed)

I want to know how to do something like WPF EventSetter in WinUI3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no equivalent of a WPF `EventSetter` in WinUI.

But you could replace the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and explicitly add a `ComboBox` with an event handler to its `CellEditingTemplate`.

Comment: I did like this.

<ctWinUI:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Primary Key" Width="150">
 <ctWinUI:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
   <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrimaryKey" Width="150" SelectionChanged="cmbPrimaryKey_SelectionChanged" />
  </DataTemplate>
 </ctWinUI:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</ctWinUI:DataGridTemplateColumn>